# Can smoke be placed on a POI?

Tags: flash-point

We played for the first time last night, and we tried the family version to start to understand the game. The situation arose where a smoke marker came up on top of a POI marker.

The POI marker was still unknown. We searched the manual and couldn't find any reference to it, so is it ok to put the smoke marker underneath a POI marker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Placing Smoke on a POI**

Yes, you put the smoke on the same space as the POI, and the POI is unaffected.  If the smoke later turns into fire, the POI will then be removed.

**Placing a POI on Smoke**

In the family version (page 6 of the rules), yes.  They even eliminate the smoke for you!

> If the Target space has a Fire or Smoke marker, remove that Fire/Smoke
>   marker before placing the POI marker.

However in the experienced game (page 10 of the rules), you adjust their position instead.

> In the Experienced game a POI may only be placed in a space without a
>   Threat marker (Fire or Smoke), Firefighter or another POI. If the POI
>   Replenishment Target space is invalid, then use this diagram to
>   redirect the POI. Begin in the Target space and follow the path
>   created by the arrows as shown until you reach a valid space. The
>   arrows are also placed on the board for easy reference during the
>   game. If there are no valid spaces on the path, reroll.

Comment: Smoke on top of a POI can definitely happen, no special rules.  The POI is not affected until the smoke turns into fire, at which point they are removed.